# Столкнулся с проблемой cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Я новичок в Java поэтому не судите строго. Я пытался потренироваться но столкнулся с проблемой что компилятор не понимает символ. Вот код:

```
public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String str = "Hello World! Its me again!";
    System.out.print(countChars(str, 'l')); 
} 
public static int countChars(String str, char ch) { 
    int i = 0; 
    int index = str.lenght() -1; 
    while (i != str.lenght) { 
        char chr = str.charAt(index); 
        if (chr.equals(ch)) { 
           i += 1; 
           index -= 1; 
        } 
        index -= 1; 
    }
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Test.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        int index = str.lenght() -1;
                       ^
  symbol:   method lenght()
  location: variable str of type String
Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        while (i != str.lenght) {
                       ^
  symbol:   variable lenght
  location: variable str of type String
Test.java:11: error: char cannot be dereferenced
            if (chr.equals(ch)) {
                   ^
3 errors
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: опечатка в слове length

Answer (score 2):

```
А зачем так сложно. Может попробовать функционалкой?
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello World! Its me again!";
        System.out.print(countChars(str, 'l'));
    }

    public static long countChars(final String str, final char ch) {
        return str.chars().filter(c->c==ch).count();
    }

}
```

Comment: не ответ на вопрос

Comment: проблема в вызове метода length () - он неправильно написан дважды. Кроме того, чар - это примитив (по сути инт), посему его нельзя сравнимать методом equals(), а нужно простым ==. Кроме того, нужно добавить инструкцию возврата. И получится гора сложночитаемого кода. Я за функционалку

Comment: Спасибо большое вам.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Удачи